# Regex in json-file provided as response-body

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I want to specify the response body for my contract in a separate json-file, one of the returned fields contains a generated database-id which is different each time I run the Unit test.
My idea was to use regex to ensure that the field exists and the value is a number, but I didn't find a way so the generated contract-test does a regex-match.

Here is my idea of what the Json could look like

```
{
  "id" : "${regex(number())}"
}
```

Is there a way (syntax) to provide regex in json-file when defining the contract?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such way to do it in the file. What you should do is use the `stubMatchers` and the `testMatchers` section (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.RELEASE/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_dynamic_properties_in_the_matchers_sections). Then you define sth like this: `request { ... stubMatchers { jsonPath('$.id', byRegex(regex(number())) }`.